# Get rows with a NULL column (non-existent) in Hbase using Thrift c++

Tags: c++, null, hbase, thrift, isnull

I need to get rows with a NULL column (non-existent) in Hbase using Thrift c++. Some rows have this column, some don't.

I have the following code with the filter, which works perfectly, but how could I get rows with the non-existent column?

```
/* Connection to the thrift server */
boost::shared_ptr<TSocket> socket(new TSocket("localhost", 9090));
boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
boost::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));

/* Creating the Hbase client*/
HbaseClient client(protocol);

try
{
    /* Open the client transport*/
    transport->open();

    /* The table name */
    std::string t("sometable");

/* Open the scanner: need to scan with a filter*/
StrVec columnNames;
StrMap atr_test;
TScan tscan;
std::string filterStr;
filterStr = "SingleColumnValueFilter('ColumnFamily', 'ColumnQualifier', =, 'substring:value', true, false)";
tscan.__set_filterString(filterStr);

int scanner = client.scannerOpenWithScan(t, tscan, atr_test);

while (true) {
    std::vector<TRowResult> value;
    client.scannerGet(value, scanner);
        // Print value
        for (CellMap::const_iterator it = value[0].columns.begin(); it != value[0].columns.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << "     " << it->first << " => " << it->second.value << ";\n";
        }

    }
}
```

I've read about setFilterIfMissing here - [How to filter out rows with given column(not null)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858995/how-to-filter-out-rows-with-given-columnnot-null), but how could I implement it in my code?
Or maybe there is some other solution?

Comment: you can use Null comparator.